# $O(n,\mathbb R)$ of all orthogonal matrices is a closed subset of $M(n,\mathbb R).$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, proof-verification

> Let $M(n,\mathbb R)$ be endowed with the norm $(a_{ij})_{n\times n}\mapsto\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2}.$ Then the set $O(n,\mathbb R)$ of all orthogonal matrices is a closed subset of $M(n,\mathbb R).$

**My Attempt:** Let $f:M(n,\mathbb R)\to M(n,\mathbb R):A\mapsto AA^t.$ Choose a sequence $\{A_k=(a^k_{ij})\}\subset M(n,\mathbb R)$ such that $A_k\to A=(a_{ij})$ for chosen $A\in M(n,\mathbb R).$ Then $\forall~i,j,$ $a_{ij}^k\to a_{ij}$ in $\mathbb R.$

Now $A_kA_k^t=(\sum_{p=1}^n a_{ip}^ka_{jp}^k)~\forall~k\in\mathbb Z^+.$

Choose $i,j\in\{1,2,...,n\}.$ Then for $p=1,2,...,n;~a_{ip}^k\to a_{ip},~a_{jp}^k\to a_{jp}$ in $\mathbb R\implies \sum_{p=1}^n a_{ip}^ka_{jp}^k\to \sum_{p=1}^n a_{ip}a_{jp}$ in $\mathbb R.$

So $(\sum_{p=1}^n a_{ip}^ka_{jp}^k)\to (\sum_{p=1}^n a_{ip}a_{jp})\implies A_kA_k^t\to AA^t.$

So $f$ is continuous on $M(n,\mathbb R).$

Now $O(n,\mathbb R)=f^{-1}(\{I\}).$ The singleton set $\{I\}$ being closed in $M(n,\mathbb R),$ $O(n,\mathbb R)$ is closed in $M(n,\mathbb R).$

> I'm not absolutely sure about the steps. Is't a correct attempt?

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: Another approach is to use the determinant as a map : Det: from $M(n, \mathbb R)$ into $\mathbb R$ , which one can show is continuous. Then $O(n, \mathbb R) $ is the inverse image under Det of the closed set {$-1$}$\cup$ {$1$} under the continuous map Det, and so $ O(n,\mathbb R )$ is the union of two closed subsets, so it is closed in $M(n, \mathbb R )$.

Comment: @FBD: Not every matrix with determinant $\pm 1$ is orthogonal. For example, $\mathrm{diag}(2,1/2)$.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, I fell for the bad-old: All A are B implies all B are A. 
I should know better by now.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: Thank you sir.

Comment: @SritiMallick : If $(A_k) \to A$ , then it is easy to observe that  $(A^t_k) \to A^t$ , now $M(n, \mathbb R)$ is a normed linear space , so if two sequences $(x_m)$ , $(y_m)$ converges to $x,y$ respectively , then $(x_my_m)$ converges to $xy$ , thus if $(A_k) \to A$ , then also $(A^t_k) \to A^t$ implies that $(A_kA_k^t) \to AA^t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be quicker to observe that $f$ is a vector of polynomials in the natural coordinates, and polynomials are continuous, so $f$ is continuous.